# How to get rid of Jagged edges in Android OpenGL ES?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have the following code:

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
    //gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

But still the edges are severely jagged in Android Emulator. What is the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the best way is to use Multisampling ( Antialiasing ). Since you use the emulator this is not an option for you. ( Multismapling supported in OpenGL ES 2.0 but the emulator does not support 2.0 )
According to the OpenGL specification, the device can ignore the glHint you set, so don't expect to much from it.
The GL_DITHER is a way to 'fake' 24bit color depth from 16bit color depth basically it has nothing to do with the edges.

Altho there is an old method to 'fake' antialiasing, its a same that I never used so I cant tell you how, but you can find some hints on the web.

From [OpenGL docs](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendFunc.xml)

> Blend function (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA) is also useful for rendering antialiased points and lines in arbitrary order.
>
> Polygon antialiasing is optimized using blend function (GL_SRC_ALPHA_SATURATE, GL_ONE) with polygons sorted from nearest to farthest.

Comment: For the record, in case someone comes across this: AVDs now support OpenGL ES 2.0 via hopst GPU deployment (optional, note the checkbox).

Comment: FYI, An approach to enabling multisampling, which does not require writing shaders as in thakis answer, can be found in svdree's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7388176/199364  In my comment there I link to sample code that looks like it uses his approach.

Answer (score 13):

http://code.google.com/p/gdc2011-android-opengl/ has sample code for multisampling.

Comment: It's no longer available on Google Code

Comment: The archive is here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/gdc2011-android-opengl/source/default/source

Answer (score 1):

You are turning on polygon smoothing using a "hint".  A hint is just that a "hint" to the implementation that you want the polygon edges smoothed.  The implementation is free to ignore it if it wants.

This is exactly what it is doing.

Furthermore it is highly likely that you simply can't turn on anti-aliasing on android devices because they are just not powerful enough to do it.  This may be different between handsets but, again, you are setting a hint.

Comment: Ok so is there alternative solution to jagged edges rather than giving a hint via API? I do not know if Emulator support anti aliasing. Can an experienced Android developer confirm this? I am using API level 8 build target 2.2.

Comment: @Alan: You can always fake anti-aliasing by rendering to a buffer twice as wide (or tall or both) and then renderit to the background with bi-linear to get anti-aliasing but I am not aware of a way to turn anti-aliasing on on Android...

Comment: I am still busy working on other issues in OpenGl and will write back once I have tested suggestions described here.

Answer (score 1):

I just went through the same issues as you. I think what you're looking for is the following line of code:

```
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
```

Comment: No, that has to do with texturing pixels inside of a shape, to make sure the texture colors blend smoothly. The question is about EDGES. For example, along the silhouette of a 3D model. Or the final edge of a triangle fan, against a much lighter or darker background.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try on a device. I don't trust the emulator for visual/graphics-related issues.
2. Try `gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DITHER);`. I'm not sure if this is on by default. Also: this makes drawing slower.

Comment: -1. Dithering has nothing to do with jagged edges, but with reducing banding when a low bit-depth is used for the frame buffer (16bits per pixel etc).