# How to do Multisampling in Android OpenGL ES?

Tags: android, opengl-es

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get rid of Jagged edges in Android OpenGL ES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934367/how-to-get-rid-of-jagged-edges-in-android-opengl-es)

I want to do Antialiasing in my appliction.But it doesn't work no matter what I did.
My code is

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config){        
    g10 = gl;
    gl.glClearColor(0f, 0, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glTexParameterx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
            GL10.GL_REPEAT);
    gl.glTexParameterx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
            GL10.GL_REPEAT);

    gl.glSampleCoverage(1.f, true);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_MULTISAMPLE);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_POINT_SMOOTH); 
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_SAMPLE_COVERAGE);
    gl.glPointSize(8); 
    gl.glLineWidth(5); 
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_POINT_SMOOTH_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST); // Make round points, not square points 
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST); // Antialias the lines
}

public void draw(GL10 gl){
    gl.glClearColor(0f, 0, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_MODULATE);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTexture[0]);  
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);   

    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, m_TexBuffer[i]);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, m_VertexBuffer[i]);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, vertexCount, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mIndexBuffer);     

}
```

It didn't do any work.Please tell me why. Thank you.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934367/how-to-get-rid-of-jagged-edges-in-android-opengl-es/ From there: "http://code.google.com/p/gdc2011-android-opengl/ has sample code for multisampling."

Comment: Even though this is marked as a duplicate, see svdree's answer below for an approach that is NOT covered in the answers to that other question, and does NOT require shader code. And follow the link in my comment re svdree, for someone's example code (which I have not tried myself).

Answer (score 11):

If you want to do FSAA, you need to create an EGL context with multisampling enabled. Write an [EGLConfigChooser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.EGLConfigChooser.html) that returns a multisampling config (specify 1 for [EGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/microedition/khronos/egl/EGL10.html#EGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS)), and pass it to [setEGLConfigChooser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setEGLConfigChooser%28android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.EGLConfigChooser%29).

Comment: This looks like complete example code for writing such a chooser: https://code.google.com/p/gdc2011-android-opengl/source/browse/trunk/src/com/example/gdc11/MultisampleConfigChooser.java?r=2  To me this seems much simpler than the link thakis suggests, which uses shaders (though you can use those shaders as-is, you don't need to understand them, so perhaps thakis approach is just as easy to use).

Comment: Isn't this a link to the same thing I'm linking to?