# Does OpenGL ES 1.x support polygon smoothing using anti-aliasing or multisampling?

Tags: android, opengl-es, antialiasing, multisampling

I'm loading 3d model in wavefront .obj format, and display it on the screen of an Android device. I'm using min3d library for loading obj and rendering, and the min3d library uses openGL ES 1.x. The problem is the 3d model is not smoothly rendered (The edges of the 3d model aren't smooth).

I don't know much about openGL ES, and I've read about questions in this forum and didn't get much information about specific openGL ES 1.x problem. I got something about anti-aliasing and multisampling to render edges more smoothly, but most of the answers direct to openGL ES 2.0

Is there any way I could improve my graphics with openGL ES 1.x?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I am working on very similar issue. After browsing for a hour, found few interesting links. hope this helps.

http://agileroute.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/how-to-emulate-anti-aliasing-in-opengl-es-1-1/

[How to get rid of Jagged edges in Android OpenGL ES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934367/how-to-get-rid-of-jagged-edges-in-android-opengl-es)

[How to do Multisampling in Android OpenGL ES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379710/how-to-do-multisampling-in-android-opengl-es)

Comment: The second and the third link suggest solutions in openGL ES 2.0.
Could the first link be applied to the texture of 3d objects? I read the article and I don't really grasp whether the solution can be applied to 3d objects and how to do it

Comment: (The first article)It's only anti-aliasing the colors in the edge of the texture, but in 3d model, the edge of the 3d model in certain perspective could be the colors anywhere in the texture, right?

Comment: In Min3D library setting pointSmoothing & lineSmoothing to true.  Iwas able to smooth the rendering to an extent. Though I was not able to get rid of it completely.